# Computing amount of information flows among two adjacent nodes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

For my research I would need to find a measurement that can quantify the amount of information flows among two adjacent nodes in a graph in order to see how similar two nodes to each other. in other words, what if nodes A and B are two adjacent nodes and nodes A and C are also two adjacent nodes, but I would like to see which two nodes are more similar to each other: A and B or A and C?

I have found a source where information loss was used to assess the level of similarity of two adjacent nodes, however, I am trying to find more efficient ways to do that.

The graph is weighted but undirected. Further, since for real-world graphs, labels are not available for the entire set of nodes, so I do not think relying on the label information would be helpful to assess nodes' level of similarity.

Comment: You'll need to specify what the graph represents, and is it labelled, directed or undirected?, and is it weighted?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AaronDefazio. The question has been modified accordingly.

Comment: I think we still need more context to help. Is the graph representing a probabilistic graphical model (i.e. a Markov random field), or something else?

Comment: Similarity of nodes strongly depends on the application. In social graphs, for instance, similarity can be accomplished by counting the number of [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#k-Cores) the two nodes lie in simultaneously. May this is something you are looking for?